# Split row values to columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, t-sql, tsqlt

Input Table

```
Id 
1,2,3
6,8,1,2,5
4,9,2,1
6,7,8
```

I need output like this

```
Id1 id2 id3 id4   id5
1    2   3  Null  Null
6    8   1   2    5
4    9   2   1    Null
6    7   8  Null  Null
```

Comment: Why sqlite and sql-server in your tags? Remove the unrelevant tag.

Comment: Don't store delimited data like this. It is awful to work with because it violates 1NF.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55139945/sql-transpose-row-to-columns

Comment: Export the data and re-import it.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what results did you get?  And what DBMS are you using, SQL Server **or** SQLite?

Answer (score 2):

If you can't re-import as Gordon suggested, try this:

```
Select A.ID
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1  = xDim.value('/x[1]','int')
                      ,Pos2  = xDim.value('/x[2]','int')
                      ,Pos3  = xDim.value('/x[3]','int')
                      ,Pos4  = xDim.value('/x[4]','int')
                      ,Pos5  = xDim.value('/x[5]','int')
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace([Id],',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

[image]