# SQL: how to transpose rows into columns (another approach needed)

Tags: sql-server, multiple-columns, rows, transpose

There is a good answer to a *similar* problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55139945/sql-transpose-row-to-columns).

However, the solutions provided rely on a "pivot", which is an ID column of some sort. What if I don't have an ID, and I don't necessarily want to slow my query down by creating one with `ROW_NUMBER()` either.

Sample data:

```
MyDataColumn
CRDB1901SAUTSVCNXMN0004666000001
CRDB1901SAUTSV
CNXMN0004666
CRDB1901SAUTSVCNXMN0004683000001
CRDB1901SAUTSV
CNXMN0004683
CRDB1901SAUTSVCNSHK021697000001
CRDB1901SAUTSV
CNSHK021697
```

The only given is that there is a pattern of three distinct values in my column. So for every 4th row repeat the transpose. I want this..

```
COLA                             COLB           COLC
CRDB1901SAUTSVCNXMN0004666000001 CRDB1901SAUTSV CNXMN0004666
CRDB1901SAUTSVCNXMN0004683000001 CRDB1901SAUTSV CNXMN0004683
CRDB1901SAUTSVCNSHK021697000001  CRDB1901SAUTSV CNSHK021697
etc
```

Here is my attempt, but I get "cannot be bound" errors on src.ManifestID

```
select src.ManifestID, [1], [2], [3]
from
(
  SELECT a.Token AS ManifestID
        FROM VisitManifests AS vm
            CROSS APPLY dbo.fnTokenizer(vm.Note, ':') AS a
        WHERE CHARINDEX('Manifest ID:', vm.Note) > 0
          AND CHARINDEX('Message ID:', vm.Note) > 0
          AND CHARINDEX('Manifest ID:', vm.Note) < CHARINDEX('Message ID:', vm.Note)
          AND a.Token > 1
) as src
pivot
(
  max(src.ManifestID)
  for ManifestID in ([1],[2],[3])
) piv;
```

Comment: Rows in a relational database have **no defined sort order**. There is no such thing as the "fourth row" unless you have some column that can be used for an `order by`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name added tag - SQL server. I am looking at the PIVOT feature. There must be a way to "instruct" SQL server to pivot on the 4th row

Comment: Again: there is no such thing as the "4th row" _unless_ you have something to sort the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try self join as below. If I guess correct, the first part of COLA is COLB and Middle part of COLA is COLC and finally the last part in COLA is a sequence number. If the above logic is always TRUE, this following script should serve your purpose.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.MyDataColumn ColA,
B.MyDataColumn ColB,
C.MyDataColumn ColC
FROM your_table A
INNER JOIN your_table B 
    ON A.MyDataColumn LIKE ''+B.MyDataColumn+'%' 
    AND A.MyDataColumn <> B.MyDataColumn
INNER JOIN your_table C 
    ON A.MyDataColumn LIKE '%'+C.MyDataColumn+'%' 
    AND A.MyDataColumn <> C.MyDataColumn 
    AND B.MyDataColumn  <> C.MyDataColumn
```

Output is-

```
ColA                                ColB            ColC
CRDB1901SAUTSVCNSHK021697000001     CRDB1901SAUTSV  CNSHK021697
CRDB1901SAUTSVCNXMN0004666000001    CRDB1901SAUTSV  CNXMN0004666
CRDB1901SAUTSVCNXMN0004683000001    CRDB1901SAUTSV  CNXMN0004683
```

Comment: I added a CTE to your query to improve performance, as my table is an extended SELECT